# Minimal .gitlab-ci.yml file for a plain HTML website

Tags: html, gitlab, gitlab-ci.yml, gitlab-pages

### Website content

```
.
├── index.html
└── images/
    ├── a.jpg
    ├── b.jpg
    └── c.jpg
```

I wonder if the following is still valid and reliable. I found it on a [blog post](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2016/04/07/gitlab-pages-setup/#add-gitlab-ci) written in 2016.

```
pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - mkdir .public
  - cp -r * .public
  - mv .public public
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
  only:
  - main
```

Is the [current CI template](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Pages/HTML.gitlab-ci.yml) any better?

```
pages:
  stage: deploy
  environment: production
  script:
    - mkdir .public
    - cp -r ./* .public
    - rm -rf public
    - mv .public public
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
```

Comment: Whether that job is configured "valid" can be checked through Gitlabs own linters. Whether it is reliable or whether the other is "better" depends on what you want to achieve. Anything not working with them?

Answer (score 0):

This worked quite easily for me in (2023)

```
pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - mkdir .public
  - cp -r * .public
  - mv .public public
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
  only:
  - master
```